# Is it possible to have SEND-SMS AND RECEIVE_SMS uses permissions in a single project?

Tags: android, sms

good day to all. 
I am fairly new to android development. Your responses on this issue will highly appreciated.

In my project I have to receive and send sms. For receiving part, I am using a Broadcast Receiver and for sending part I use a normal Activity. Here the Broadcast Receiver receives the sms and transfer some data to the Activity I just mentioned. Then activity perform some tasks and produce some results. I need those results to be sent as an sms.

I have used SEND_SMS and RECEIVE_SMS uses permissions in the manifest file. But this application gives me an exception on the emulator. But when I tested sending part and receiving part in 2 separate projects, it's working fine without any exceptions. So I guess there is nothing wrong with the code (or logic). 
Now, why this exception is thrown? Is it possible to have SEND_SMS and RECEIVE_SMS uses permission withing a same project(same manifest) ?
I have used SmsManager to send sms.
Your response will be highly appreciated.

Here is the LogCat details:

```
11-22 12:26:00.355: ERROR/Zygote(33): setreuid() failed. errno: 2
11-22 12:26:09.295: ERROR/Zygote(33): setreuid() failed. errno: 17
11-22 12:26:11.125: ERROR/BatteryService(66): usbOnlinePath not found
11-22 12:26:11.125: ERROR/BatteryService(66): batteryVoltagePath not found
11-22 12:26:11.125: ERROR/BatteryService(66): batteryTemperaturePath not found
11-22 12:26:11.155: ERROR/SurfaceFlinger(66): Couldn't open /sys/power/wait_for_fb_sleep or /sys/power/wait_for_fb_wake
11-22 12:26:32.497: ERROR/EventHub(66): could not get driver version for /dev/input/mouse0, Not a typewriter
11-22 12:26:32.605: ERROR/EventHub(66): could not get driver version for /dev/input/mice, Not a typewriter
11-22 12:26:33.756: ERROR/System(66): Failure starting core service
11-22 12:26:33.756: ERROR/System(66): java.lang.SecurityException
11-22 12:26:33.756: ERROR/System(66):     at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
11-22 12:26:33.756: ERROR/System(66):     at android.os.ServiceManagerProxy.addService(ServiceManagerNative.java:146)
11-22 12:26:33.756: ERROR/System(66):     at android.os.ServiceManager.addService(ServiceManager.java:72)
11-22 12:26:33.756: ERROR/System(66):     at com.android.server.ServerThread.run(SystemServer.java:184)
11-22 12:26:38.805: ERROR/SoundPool(66): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
11-22 12:26:38.815: ERROR/SoundPool(66): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
11-22 12:26:38.815: ERROR/SoundPool(66): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
11-22 12:26:38.825: ERROR/SoundPool(66): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
11-22 12:26:39.035: ERROR/SoundPool(66): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
11-22 12:26:50.545: ERROR/ThrottleService(66): Could not open GPS configuration file /etc/gps.conf
11-22 12:26:57.865: ERROR/logwrapper(150): executing /system/bin/tc failed: No such file or directory
11-22 12:26:57.995: ERROR/logwrapper(152): executing /system/bin/tc failed: No such file or directory
11-22 12:26:58.005: ERROR/logwrapper(153): executing /system/bin/tc failed: No such file or directory
11-22 12:27:12.875: ERROR/ActivityManager(66): ANR in com.android.settings
11-22 12:27:12.875: ERROR/ActivityManager(66): Reason: Broadcast of Intent { act=android.intent.action.CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS cmp=com.android.settings/.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider (has extras) }
11-22 12:27:12.875: ERROR/ActivityManager(66): Load: 2.93 / 0.78 / 0.26
11-22 12:27:12.875: ERROR/ActivityManager(66): CPU usage from 10994ms to 2618ms ago:
11-22 12:27:12.875: ERROR/ActivityManager(66):   ronsoft.openwnn: 209% = 122% user + 86% kernel / faults: 3908 minor 5 major
11-22 12:27:12.875: ERROR/ActivityManager(66):   m.android.phone: 168% = 84% user + 84% kernel / faults: 3177 minor 7 major
11-22 12:27:12.875: ERROR/ActivityManager(66):   system_server: 150% = 118% user + 31% kernel / faults: 428 minor 3 major
11-22 12:27:12.875: ERROR/ActivityManager(66):   ndroid.launcher: 118% = 65% user + 52% kernel / faults: 2921 minor 3 major
11-22 12:27:12.875: ERROR/ActivityManager(66):   ndroid.settings: 118% = 47% user + 70% kernel / faults: 2956 minor 7 major
11-22 12:27:12.875: ERROR/ActivityManager(66):   bootanimation: 18% = 15% user + 2% kernel
11-22 12:27:12.875: ERROR/ActivityManager(66):   app_process: 13% = 9% user + 4% kernel / faults: 241 minor
11-22 12:27:12.875: ERROR/ActivityManager(66):   adbd: 11% = 0% user + 11% kernel
11-22 12:27:12.875: ERROR/ActivityManager(66): TOTAL: 100% = 70% user + 29% kernel
11-22 12:27:22.035: ERROR/ActivityManager(66): ANR in jp.co.omronsoft.openwnn
11-22 12:27:22.035: ERROR/ActivityManager(66): Reason: Executing service jp.co.omronsoft.openwnn/.OpenWnnJAJP
11-22 12:27:22.035: ERROR/ActivityManager(66): Load: 3.31 / 0.94 / 0.32
11-22 12:27:22.035: ERROR/ActivityManager(66): CPU usage from 10962ms to 1406ms ago:
11-22 12:27:22.035: ERROR/ActivityManager(66):   system_server: 47% = 34% user + 12% kernel / faults: 511 minor
11-22 12:27:22.035: ERROR/ActivityManager(66):   app_process: 15% = 14% user + 1% kernel / faults: 420 minor
11-22 12:27:22.035: ERROR/ActivityManager(66):   ronsoft.openwnn: 9% = 7% user + 1% kernel / faults: 394 minor
11-22 12:27:22.035: ERROR/ActivityManager(66):   ndroid.launcher: 9% = 6% user + 2% kernel / faults: 741 minor
11-22 12:27:22.035: ERROR/ActivityManager(66):   bootanimation: 6% = 5% user + 0% kernel
11-22 12:27:22.035: ERROR/ActivityManager(66):   m.android.phone: 6% = 4% user + 1% kernel / faults: 267 minor
11-22 12:27:22.035: ERROR/ActivityManager(66):   adbd: 1% = 0% user + 0% kernel
11-22 12:27:22.035: ERROR/ActivityManager(66):   logcat: 1% = 0% user + 0% kernel
11-22 12:27:22.035: ERROR/ActivityManager(66):   events/0: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
11-22 12:27:22.035: ERROR/ActivityManager(66):   servicemanager: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
11-22 12:27:22.035: ERROR/ActivityManager(66):  -ndroid.settings: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
11-22 12:27:22.035: ERROR/ActivityManager(66): TOTAL: 100% = 75% user + 25% kernel
11-22 12:27:33.342: ERROR/HierarchicalStateMachine(66): TetherMaster - unhandledMessage: msg.what=3
```

Comment: Can you show us the LogCat stack trace for the exception that is thrown when you use both permissions? For all you know it could have been something wrong in your code.

Comment: Well, as I specified, the exception is thrown when the emulator runs. Here it is,
 "The application ProjectName(process packageName) has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again. "
Thanks for your attention Mr. Matt Quiros

Comment: What I meant is, if you're using Eclipse to write the app, there should be a window called "LogCat" where all the system messages (and not the dialogs, like in your example) are located. You can open LogCat by going to Window -> Show View -> Other -> Android -> LogCat, then run your program, and when you see a huge block of messages in red, paste it here.

Comment: I have added the LogCat details as you said. I couldn't add it to a comment, so I updated my original question by adding LogCat details.

Comment: It seems you copy-pasted the wrong logs. We're looking for a "stack trace" of the `Exception` that gets thrown. In LogCat, you will see that as the huge block of red logs that appear when "The application has stopped unexpectedly" message appears. It looks something like this: http://pastie.org/5416837 Also, please properly paste the logs by beginning each line with a `> `.

Comment: Nothing but the above LogCat details are displayed when the time the exception is thrown.

Answer (score 2):

I think [this](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/sms-messaging-android) tutorial might walk you through your problem. There are both the modules, sending and receiving sms.

Comment: Well, thanks kittu88 for the link. I have already tried that code before posting my question here. And I use the similar kind of logic in my application except, instead of using PendingIntents or Intents, I am using SmsManager class only. But still an exception is thrown when emulator runs..

Comment: @kitu88 The Google administrators for the Google Play Store consider the RECEIVE_SMS permission (in the tutorial you mention) to be dangerous. As a result, an app that contains the permission will be rejected. Then the developer has to submit a form to Google Play administrators for approval. Other developers have mentioned the process is awful with feedback taking weeks and receiving outright rejections with either no explanations or generic feedback. Any ideas on how to avoid?